# Retain square layout with GridSpec

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-gridspec

How do I align the GridSpec to look like this?

```
|‾ ‾ ‾ ‾|  |‾ ‾|  |‾ ‾|
|       |  |_ _|  |_ _|
|       |  |‾ ‾|  |‾ ‾|
|_ _ _ _|  |_ _|  |_ _|
```

I have tried the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec
import numpy as np

gs = GridSpec(2, 3, hspace=-0.1)
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[:2, :2])
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 2])
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1, 2])

ax1.set_aspect("equal")
ax2.set_aspect("equal")
ax3.set_aspect("equal")
 
plt.show()
```

output:

[image]

But when adjusting the width and height of the plot manually, the spacing is not retained:

[image]

Is it possible to specify this constraint somehow?

Answer (score 1):

After reading this [tutorial page](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/arranging_axes.html), this is the closest I could get:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec

fig = plt.figure(constrained_layout=True)
gs0 = fig.add_gridspec(1, 2)

gs00 = gs0[0].subgridspec(1, 1)
ax0 = fig.add_subplot(gs00[0, 0])

gs01 = gs0[1].subgridspec(2, 2)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs01[0, 0])
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs01[0, 1])
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(gs01[1, 0])
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(gs01[1, 1])
fig
```

[image]